# iPad making sense of the Crash Report

Tags: ipad, crash, report

Are there any hints here as to where/what is causing the app to crash?

It happens while retrieving a Web Service collection of objects.

```
Incident Identifier: 577D74D6-DAFB-44B7-AA06-2E80C9AF9EE4
CrashReporter Key:   98301378d20acc056591628b8782f0eef18a5147
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         InterfaithExplorer [511]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/E3624F4D-6AB7-470A-9C2B-082D4AD3E3D1/InterfaithExplorer.app/InterfaithExplorer
Identifier:      InterfaithExplorer
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-11-22 14:08:41.904 +0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.2.2 (7B500)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x2fe0e65e ImageLoaderMachOClassic::findClosestSymbol(void const*, void const**) const + 142
1   InterfaithExplorer              0x00037198 0x1000 + 221592
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00003f86 dladdr + 42
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00054fde backtrace_symbols + 54
4   InterfaithExplorer              0x00506250 0x1000 + 5263952
5   InterfaithExplorer              0x0052550c 0x1000 + 5391628
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00077ba4 _sigtramp + 36
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00003734 mach_msg + 44
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0002296e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 1150
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000224da CFRunLoopRunInMode + 42
10  GraphicsServices                0x000030d4 GSEventRunModal + 108
11  GraphicsServices                0x00003180 GSEventRun + 56
12  UIKit                           0x0000342a -[UIApplication _run] + 374
13  UIKit                           0x00001954 UIApplicationMain + 636
14  InterfaithExplorer              0x00025858 0x1000 + 149592
15  InterfaithExplorer              0x0000dae8 0x1000 + 51944
16  InterfaithExplorer              0x00112818 0x1000 + 1120280
17  InterfaithExplorer              0x002d4b6c 0x1000 + 2964332
18  InterfaithExplorer              0x004ef588 0x1000 + 5170568
19  InterfaithExplorer              0x005ce3d8 0x1000 + 6083544
20  InterfaithExplorer              0x005d06cc 0x1000 + 6092492
21  InterfaithExplorer              0x005cfe64 0x1000 + 6090340
22  InterfaithExplorer              0x004f61a0 0x1000 + 5198240
23  InterfaithExplorer              0x004eac80 0x1000 + 5151872
24  InterfaithExplorer              0x00002d18 0x1000 + 7448

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000016b8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002ecce semaphore_wait + 2
2   InterfaithExplorer              0x00565920 0x1000 + 5654816
3   InterfaithExplorer              0x005f61bc 0x1000 + 6246844
4   InterfaithExplorer              0x0061b8a0 0x1000 + 6400160
5   InterfaithExplorer              0x0064a8ac 0x1000 + 6592684
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a786 _pthread_start + 242
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00070070 thread_start + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00001668 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00003734 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0002296e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 1150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000224da CFRunLoopRunInMode + 42
4   WebCore                         0x0000268a RunWebThread(void*) + 286
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a786 _pthread_start + 242
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00070070 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00001668 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00003734 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0002296e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 1150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000224da CFRunLoopRunInMode + 42
4   Foundation                      0x00017a4c +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 164
5   Foundation                      0x00010bca -[NSThread main] + 38
6   Foundation                      0x0007ccf8 __NSThread__main__ + 896
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a786 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00070070 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00025968 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00072d7c __CFSocketManager + 552
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a786 _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00070070 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00077b60 __semwait_signal_nocancel + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00077710 nanosleep$NOCANCEL + 108
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00070038 usleep$NOCANCEL + 36
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008d1c4 __abort + 68
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008d216 abort + 62
5   InterfaithExplorer              0x00649384 0x1000 + 6587268
6   InterfaithExplorer              0x0063cde4 0x1000 + 6536676
7   InterfaithExplorer              0x0063c794 0x1000 + 6535060
8   InterfaithExplorer              0x006430c8 0x1000 + 6561992
9   InterfaithExplorer              0x0064376c 0x1000 + 6563692
10  InterfaithExplorer              0x00643a4c 0x1000 + 6564428
11  InterfaithExplorer              0x005d22cc 0x1000 + 6099660
12  InterfaithExplorer              0x005d273c 0x1000 + 6100796
13  InterfaithExplorer              0x005eec7c 0x1000 + 6216828
14  InterfaithExplorer              0x002a3430 0x1000 + 2761776
15  InterfaithExplorer              0x0029fb78 0x1000 + 2747256
16  InterfaithExplorer              0x0029f924 0x1000 + 2746660
17  InterfaithExplorer              0x0029f76c 0x1000 + 2746220
18  InterfaithExplorer              0x001153f8 0x1000 + 1131512
19  InterfaithExplorer              0x00114c58 0x1000 + 1129560
20  InterfaithExplorer              0x001239dc 0x1000 + 1190364
21  InterfaithExplorer              0x002d4b6c 0x1000 + 2964332
22  InterfaithExplorer              0x004ef588 0x1000 + 5170568
23  InterfaithExplorer              0x005ce3d8 0x1000 + 6083544
24  InterfaithExplorer              0x005d0fc8 0x1000 + 6094792
25  InterfaithExplorer              0x005d4c9c 0x1000 + 6110364
26  InterfaithExplorer              0x005f1b78 0x1000 + 6228856
27  InterfaithExplorer              0x005f3e24 0x1000 + 6237732
28  InterfaithExplorer              0x005f61bc 0x1000 + 6246844
29  InterfaithExplorer              0x0061b8a0 0x1000 + 6400160
30  InterfaithExplorer              0x0064a8ac 0x1000 + 6592684
31  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a786 _pthread_start + 242
32  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00070070 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000797ac __semwait_signal + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00003212 nanosleep + 118
2   InterfaithExplorer              0x0061cb64 0x1000 + 6404964
3   InterfaithExplorer              0x005f781c 0x1000 + 6252572
4   InterfaithExplorer              0x002b6794 0x1000 + 2840468
5   InterfaithExplorer              0x00123844 0x1000 + 1189956
6   InterfaithExplorer              0x002d4b6c 0x1000 + 2964332
7   InterfaithExplorer              0x004ef588 0x1000 + 5170568
8   InterfaithExplorer              0x005ce3d8 0x1000 + 6083544
9   InterfaithExplorer              0x005d0fc8 0x1000 + 6094792
10  InterfaithExplorer              0x005d4c9c 0x1000 + 6110364
11  InterfaithExplorer              0x005f1b78 0x1000 + 6228856
12  InterfaithExplorer              0x005f3e24 0x1000 + 6237732
13  InterfaithExplorer              0x005f61bc 0x1000 + 6246844
14  InterfaithExplorer              0x0061b8a0 0x1000 + 6400160
15  InterfaithExplorer              0x0064a8ac 0x1000 + 6592684
16  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a786 _pthread_start + 242
17  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00070070 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00056790 poll + 8
1   InterfaithExplorer              0x00629838 0x1000 + 6457400
2   InterfaithExplorer              0x005f0704 0x1000 + 6223620
3   InterfaithExplorer              0x005f61bc 0x1000 + 6246844
4   InterfaithExplorer              0x0061b8a0 0x1000 + 6400160
5   InterfaithExplorer              0x0064a8ac 0x1000 + 6592684
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a786 _pthread_start + 242
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00070070 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000797ac __semwait_signal + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002e976 _pthread_cond_wait + 742
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0003538a pthread_cond_timedwait + 30
3   InterfaithExplorer              0x00608d28 0x1000 + 6323496
4   InterfaithExplorer              0x00618a00 0x1000 + 6388224
5   InterfaithExplorer              0x005f005c 0x1000 + 6221916
6   InterfaithExplorer              0x005f61bc 0x1000 + 6246844
7   InterfaithExplorer              0x0061b8a0 0x1000 + 6400160
8   InterfaithExplorer              0x0064a8ac 0x1000 + 6592684
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a786 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00070070 thread_start + 0

Thread 9:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000797ac __semwait_signal + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002e976 _pthread_cond_wait + 742
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0003538a pthread_cond_timedwait + 30
3   InterfaithExplorer              0x00608d28 0x1000 + 6323496
4   InterfaithExplorer              0x00618a00 0x1000 + 6388224
5   InterfaithExplorer              0x005f005c 0x1000 + 6221916
6   InterfaithExplorer              0x005f61bc 0x1000 + 6246844
7   InterfaithExplorer              0x0061b8a0 0x1000 + 6400160
8   InterfaithExplorer              0x0064a8ac 0x1000 + 6592684
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a786 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00070070 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x007ca32c    r1: 0x000016ec      r2: 0x007c64e0      r3: 0x00000024
    r4: 0x00506240    r5: 0x2fe2790c      r6: 0x00721000      r7: 0x2fffe9dc
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x007c64e0     r10: 0x0761617c     r11: 0x07616170
    ip: 0x00732004    sp: 0x2fffe9b8      lr: 0x000371a0      pc: 0x2fe0e65e
  cpsr: 0x80000030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x6e6fff +InterfaithExplorer armv6  <14d6af3676feff93847378b62bf1e4be> /var/mobile/Applications/E3624F4D-6AB7-470A-9C2B-082D4AD3E3D1/InterfaithExplorer.app/InterfaithExplorer
  0xb1c000 -   0xb1dfff  dns.so armv7  <16fad82d8b9ba83f1b97894eec8b9249> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe24fff  dyld armv7  <f519a14308c6cacb53d2ff16a041ede3> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3003d000 - 0x3003dfff  Accelerate armv7  <cf3dd3fe3d895a5d063e0f234a777dc4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3003e000 - 0x3004ffff  PersistentConnection armv7  <52455827e383f2aef935edcb780edf6d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x30062000 - 0x300d8fff  CFNetwork armv7  <24d5180cd6a86e8b0ecb665bb06ec7b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x30229000 - 0x30232fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <2e981f91a2d0c7cada7a35a3209e6988> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30333000 - 0x3042efff  Foundation armv7  <b8257c049bb1d6c8c574e8983997a238> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x30435000 - 0x3095dfff  WebCore armv7  <9cd9d51fc8a7510b86ba2a9fe20c187b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x30aae000 - 0x30ae2fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <fd72995019da645dff6444a6696e7f87> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x30ae5000 - 0x30ae5fff  vecLib armv7  <3009f6144864ee4440f338601747f1a9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30aea000 - 0x30af0fff  WebUI armv7  <e61cea4ab932840959de2bff301ebed8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
0x30af1000 - 0x30bdbfff  CoreData armv7  <d14864e536e20129c7af38cd091720b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x30bdc000 - 0x30bf2fff  AddressBook armv7  <41156e8e140b9a7590aed04a2b8d862e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30d04000 - 0x30d0ffff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <494318afb4dea7a16cd5fe1b3d021d09> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x30d10000 - 0x30d42fff  TextInput armv7  <f4024e63c56c7fe7ee1d2525273e1df1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x30d43000 - 0x30e30fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <ab354d456dbf1308b13f057f3a137697> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x30e34000 - 0x30e5ffff  MIME armv7  <63d95226d1729ed2a20131f403e13b14> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x30eb4000 - 0x30ee3fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <e0f1d6d74a1d894087c8cb516dc6f784> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x30faf000 - 0x3104cfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <2b58676c04c23d2ad82b8b63aaadef03> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x31057000 - 0x31100fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <9da09fb1fd6cd26dbd4669260ad11b8c> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3110b000 - 0x3110cfff  CoreSurface armv7  <81b2c3adcb64e8458625e6de6a505b64> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3112c000 - 0x31170fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <0539e49fe2400d30b47978ce6bdd10cb> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x31210000 - 0x3129ffff  WebKit armv7  <3da1b21b5e8b5e2fc92e6e3115155c92> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x312a0000 - 0x312d8fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <8984a9bfdaf1bfc0143266c353a2f19e> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3134d000 - 0x31367fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <70fd7701cb8a4d756fe331400fc95d70> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x314b1000 - 0x314b4fff  IOSurface armv7  <add52708e97215d3fd374ced558489f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x314b6000 - 0x31561fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <15906913aca9156d43c7c7f12a966cd3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x31562000 - 0x3156efff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <32f5cf2f0783d392f52085b4343fdf24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x3156f000 - 0x3159dfff  MobileQuickLook armv7  <930431cd17d7ec91d4b67850f12c64f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileQuickLook.framework/MobileQuickLook
0x31648000 - 0x3166cfff  Security armv7  <8b814e12a6abdc32c551a3d293bd0a22> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x31714000 - 0x317d0fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <a0392fb91f1d4081862166013c798c2e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31807000 - 0x3181dfff  RawCamera armv7  <2a45c6571bee4a8c3888e9ccf1b6632a> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x318dd000 - 0x319f4fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <609dd544d17c2f12e4a97a84b2cd445c> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x319f9000 - 0x31a2ffff  IOKit armv7  <5f9377766097ba5fbd4aa60a396fff37> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x31a4f000 - 0x31a62fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <b711ed7d5ee437a2f572c6c4b4192218> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x31a65000 - 0x31a72fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <86a545a79050fdf1221f8770045986b0> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x31a88000 - 0x31ac8fff  CoreAudio armv7  <72d79835651ba34d0a56d4c86e5aa8e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31ae1000 - 0x31b0ffff  CoreText armv7  <1c30eee80d98fbf86c79ee6d6cba19ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x31b10000 - 0x31b25fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <d446b161586cec3de986113a84e64dd4> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x31bc0000 - 0x31bc7fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <922855f7b5ca1bb151c6d3a161e85b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x31c0c000 - 0x31c31fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <aba675997e9d5b55135fea5a2441bf3e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x31c32000 - 0x31c6dfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <14a9d611a3e7e461809e191736acc3f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3223e000 - 0x33083fff  UIKit armv7  <d283c16ba9c583d070f32ded526a508b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x330a5000 - 0x330adfff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <167ecad417e416de57e8ad729ba91247> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x330f6000 - 0x330f8fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <06dcddf828a05e4488a915abe883043d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33222000 - 0x3322afff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <f8341d84de9070b09b5bdb371678a1ed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x3322f000 - 0x33237fff  AccountSettings armv7  <63a3501aa3142bf88eb9279198b12c6d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x3361c000 - 0x33632fff  EAP8021X armv7  <5bba090ab67c9f8eeeed75cec10b9ee1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x336a8000 - 0x336bdfff  OpenGLES armv7  <846301eba9a2a9546cccd8a53b16dc4e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x336be000 - 0x33708fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <fb5f5150ce320ad7ff0b611686c822ff> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33769000 - 0x3378ffff  AppSupport armv7  <43c0ef0749b3a7bda5b795a27f22b7c4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x3379d000 - 0x3380afff  ProofReader armv7  <e1625e9197f927a4d262ec5448e296d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x339cc000 - 0x339d5fff  CoreVideo armv7  <558fd565d1708990d666244e387a05ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x339d6000 - 0x339defff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <28cabe0d3d9c2ccbb2feaf61df9edcf3> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x33aec000 - 0x33bf4fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <02df5ad00b5b4f1d04626a1d82568841> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33bf9000 - 0x33c83fff  ImageIO armv7  <737134869e9ff428fad7d8a8c1cf62b1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33c84000 - 0x33d6ffff  AudioToolbox armv7  <fa54b28dcc679f78832490fcae2a3ac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x33d77000 - 0x33ecafff  CoreGraphics armv7  <5f0a81618badc0452fe7177a285d8eaf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x33eeb000 - 0x33ef0fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <c398705944d314a1099b7940d07099ea> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x33f02000 - 0x3401efff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <5ec59f45de10f1ed2d6066cef67035ff> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x34125000 - 0x3414afff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <ed7dd6421ca28a68ac6da4ee4504e8be> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3414b000 - 0x34156fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <03b2c10c7cfe9d9585bd9ee2c40a38ce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x34279000 - 0x34312fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ad8f9a5161025fa
```

84a8d4983a27c70e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have the .dSYM file that was produced when building your app.

Take a look at the Apple Developer TechNote "Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports" located at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html

I usually look at the crash reports exception description to see why the app crashed and in what thread the crash happened - thread 0 in this case.

Check the top of the call stack of thread 0 to see what method was last called...

```
ImageLoaderMachOClassic::findClosestSymbol(void const*, void const**)
```

then really really check the parameters passed to the method. Either by inspecting your source code or perhaps adding assertions. Often I find that I passed a bogus pointer to the last method called.

Comment: Thanks Niels. I use Monotouch and .Net to write the iPhone apps but that gets me in to the right direction.